# How to set content-type in HTTP POST in pentaho kettle?

Tags: post, pentaho, kettle, hubspot

I have to post a JSON to an  API (HubSpot) and API required content-type as "application/json". I tried setting content-type using HTTP POST but it was not set.

Searching the net I came to [this](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-3501#comment-183181) page and read about the patch for it. But I don't know how to apply the patch. I am using kettle version as "5.0.1-stable" and build date is " 2013-11-15_16-08-58 ".

I need to set content-type in the header as "application/json" for posting the JSON data to API.

Comment: Have you tried a nightly build or an older version? Looks like this is an older bug that has resurfaced.

Comment: I tried with version 4.4.0-stable and build date 2012-11-21 16.02.21 .
But same result. Can anyone help its very urgent.

Comment: Finally I got it done. HubSpot is REST API. I did not know that there was REST Client tool also. I used it and it worked out.
But still for those who want to do set content-type, this questions validates.

Comment: You could answer your own question. I'd be very interested in seeing what you found.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you've found a workaround, but for whom it's still relevant to set the `Content-type` on HTTP POST within PDI, [this bug](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-3177) may be of interest to you.

To make a long story short, some web servers set the charset in the Content-Type in double quotes, e.g.:

```
Content-Type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"
```

This may get you to run into `java.io.IOException: Uknown encoding "utf-8"`.

You can alter the step's code [as suggested here](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-3501).

Comment: Can you please post the actual solution instead of links to password protected sites?

Comment: @FrancoisBotha, TL;DR: no. I don't know if you've noticed or how familiar you are with Pentaho's history, but when I submitted this answer seven years ago, PDI was an open-source project just acquired by Hitachi.  I'm assuming their Jira projects are now gated for Hitachi org members' eyes only, so neither can I access the links I've referenced - again - seven years ago.

Comment: Which is why link answers are discouraged. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/200687

Comment: First off, they are not "discouraged" period; they should complement the actual answer, which is an absolutely valid point - I agree with you 100%. Secondly, I can't remember the actual bug and answer, so you can consider this "case" closed and move on.